# Can I have native back buttons in iOS app on Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

If I have a native topbar in my trigger.io iOS app, can I have a native back button (pointed on the one side) to go to previous view?

Comment: Are you using backbone.js routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for back buttons with an arrow to one side. I cannot see how this is possible natively with Trigger.io right now.

A possible workaround would be to imitate the arrow back button on your own, possibly along the lines of [this pure CSS approach](http://dream-world.us/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/).

However, I'm not sure whether you can integrate this into the native topbar without building the whole thing on your own (which leads to new issues like fixed headers on mobile devices..).

Lets hope Trigger.io will include those arrow back buttons natively.